# How to display ACF Repeater into Woocommerce Product Category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to display ACF repeater field into Woocommerce product category page, here is my code below, unable to achieve

```
<?php if(have_rows('header_img')) : while(have_rows('header_img')) : the_row();
$cat_banner = get_sub_field('image_header');
?>
<div class="header-img">
<img src="<?php echo $cat_banner ?>">
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For taxonomy you need to use the second parameter to the function "have_rows". Try the below code:

```
<?php $queried_object = get_queried_object(); ?>

<?php if(have_rows('header_img', $queried_object)) : ?>

    <?php while(have_rows('header_img', $queried_object)) : the_row();
            $cat_banner = get_sub_field('image_header');
    ?>
        <div class="header-img">
        <img src="<?php echo $cat_banner ?>">
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    
<?php endif; ?>
```